# UITableView lags on build

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uitableview, snapkit

I need help with debugging one performance issue.

#### Overview

I have two ViewController `A` and `B`. `A` pushes `B` on `UIButton` click. `B` contains `UITableView`.

#### Problem

When I click on `UIButton` in `A` UI freezes for 1-2 sec and then `B` will appear. When I remove `UITableView` from `B` then push works smooth.

#### Implementation

building cell (I am leaving labels empty):

```
addCustomSelectedBackgroundColor(.ma_tintLightBlue)
backgroundColor = .clear

// container view
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.backgroundColor = .ma_white
contentView.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 0.0))
}

// avatar
authorAvatar = AvatarView(dimension: 46.0)
containerView.addSubview(authorAvatar)
authorAvatar.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16.0)
    $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10.0)
}

// date
dateLabel = UILabel()
dateLabel.font = .ma_systemFont(ofSize: 11.0)
dateLabel.textColor = .ma_textGray
containerView.addSubview(dateLabel)
dateLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(14.0)
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16.0)
}

// author info
let authorInfoView = buildAuthorInfoView()
containerView.addSubview(authorInfoView)
authorInfoView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.centerY.equalTo(authorAvatar.snp.centerY)
    $0.leading.equalTo(authorAvatar.snp.trailing).offset(12.0)
    $0.trailing.lessThanOrEqualTo(dateLabel.snp.leading).offset(-12.0)
}

// content
contentLabel = UILabel()
contentLabel.font = .ma_systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
contentLabel.textColor = .ma_textBlack
contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
containerView.addSubview(contentLabel)
contentLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16.0)
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16.0)
    $0.top.equalTo(authorAvatar.snp.bottom).offset(8.0)
}

// bottom bar
bottomView = PostCellBottomView()
containerView.addSubview(bottomView)
bottomView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.top.equalTo(contentLabel.snp.bottom).offset(20.0)
    $0.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16.0)
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-16.0)
    $0.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
```

building tableview

```
tableView = UITableView()
tableView.customize(cellClasses: [FeedWallCell.self])
view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
}
```

customize method for tableview

```
extension UITableView {

    func customize(cellClasses: [IdentifiableTableViewCell.Type] = [],
                   headerFooterClasses: [IdentifiableTableViewHeaderFooterView.Type] = [],
                   datasource: UITableViewDataSource? = nil,
                   delegate: UITableViewDelegate? = nil) {

        backgroundColor = .clear
        separatorStyle = .none
        keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

        estimatedRowHeight = 60
        rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 60
        sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 60
        sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        self.dataSource = datasource
        self.delegate = delegate

        register(cellClasses: cellClasses)
        register(headerFooterClasses: headerFooterClasses)
    }
}
```

#### Profiling

Simple push takes 600+ ms

[image]

#### Environment

iOS11, Xcode9, iPhone6

Comment: Make sure when you pop B deinit() should called , freezing may be due to memory leaks . place deinit() in both controllers.

Comment: Nah, push freezes even for first time. So there is no other `B` in memory.

Comment: Do you added heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate?

Comment: No, I am using `tableview.rowHeight` property.

Comment: You are using SnapKit for autolayouts, try to implement same thing in new fresh project without using snapkit ,i mean native autolayout using interface builder and see performance of that app in same device.

Comment: try to use delegate and put the estimatedHeight if you are using UITableViewAutomaticDimension else directly put height in return .

Comment: UI mostly freezes when on main thread some blocking functions is there .

Comment: Show your viewcontroller B code, so that i can check how you are loading data.